# Share using facebook native app instead of browser

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am noob in js and I have to modify a js function:

I have a webpage that has a share button. this webpage has a mobile version also.
I need to open in mobile version of the website the native facebook app instead of the system default browser as it does in desktop version.

The function I have for the share button is:

```
function fb(){
        window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://example.html', '_blank', 'width=626,height=305');  
    }
```

What do I need to add to this function in order to call in mobile mode the facebook native app?

Many thanks!